# Properties of Expectation Values Under Variable Substitution

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, harmonic-oscillator

I am working on a homework problem from Griffiths QM (Problem 2.11, 3rd Edition). Specifically, I'm working on finding $\left<x^2\right>$ for the ground state and the first excited state of the harmonic oscillator centered at the origin. The (time-independent) wave functions for those two states are given by
$$\psi_0(x) = \left(\frac{m\omega}{\pi\hbar}\right)^{1/4}e^{-\frac{m\omega}{2\hbar}x^2}$$ and $$\psi_1(x) = \left(\frac{m\omega}{\pi\hbar}\right)^{1/4}\sqrt{\frac{2m\omega}{\hbar}}xe^{-\frac{m\omega}{2\hbar}x^2},$$ respectively. Griffiths suggests changing variables with $\xi \equiv \sqrt{\frac{m\omega}{\hbar}}x$ and $\alpha \equiv \left(\frac{m\omega}{\pi\hbar}\right)^{1/4}$, which gives $$\psi_0(\xi) = \alpha e^{-\xi^2/2}$$ and $$\psi_1(\xi) = \sqrt{2}\alpha \xi e^{-\xi^2/2}.$$

To find $\left<x^2\right>$, I thought I'd be smart and find it using the definition of $\xi$ like this: Since $x=\sqrt{\frac{\hbar}{m\omega}}\xi$, then $\left<x^2\right> = \left<\left(\sqrt{\frac{\hbar}{m\omega}}\xi\right)^2\right> = \frac{\hbar}{m\omega}\left<\xi^2\right>$. For the ground state, I'm using $$\left<\xi^2\right> = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\psi_0^*(\xi)\xi^2\psi_0(\xi)d\xi$$ giving $$\left<\xi^2\right> = \frac{\alpha^2\sqrt{\pi}}{2}.$$ Finally, I get $$\left<x^2\right> = \frac{\hbar}{m\omega}\frac{\alpha^2\sqrt{\pi}}{2} = \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{\hbar}{m\omega}},$$ which I know for a fact is not correct, because, for one thing, the units aren't right (the units I'm getting are m, but I should be getting m$^2$). I've narrowed the problem down to a missing factor of $\sqrt{\frac{\hbar}{m\omega}}$ which comes from converting $dx$ to $d\xi$ in the integral, but I'm wondering, what is wrong with the following equation: $$\left<x^2\right> = \frac{\hbar}{m\omega}\left<\xi^2\right>?$$

Comment: The issue is your integral that you have for $\langle\xi^2\rangle$. I would suggest starting with the integral for $\langle x^2\rangle$ and *then* make the variable substitution. You might see the issue then

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing is wrong with the equation
$$\left<x^2\right> = \frac{\hbar}{m\omega}\left<\xi^2\right>$$
it is completely correct.

However, your interpretation of the equation is wrong. If we say
$x^2 = \frac{\hbar}{m\omega}\xi^2$
(which is obviously true), then we can immediately go to $\left<x^2\right> = \frac{\hbar}{m\omega}\left<\xi^2\right>$ by simply doing the same thing to both sides of the equation--namely, putting brackets around each side. These brackets must mean *the same thing on both sides of the equation* for this to be valid, however.

What do brackets mean? They mean take the expectation value. In particular, $\langle A\rangle$ means $\int \psi(x)^*A\psi(x) dx$. It does NOT mean $\int \psi(\xi)^*A\psi(\xi) d\xi$, that is a different thing. So, to go from your correct equation to an actual calculation, you must write

$$\left<x^2\right> = \frac{\hbar}{m\omega}\left<\xi^2\right>=\frac{\hbar}{m\omega}\int\psi(x)^*\xi^2\psi(x) dx$$ and only THEN do a change of variables to write everything in terms of $\xi$.